# Where is composer's global auth.json located?

Tags: php, composer-php

Where is the global auth.json from composer located on linux?

Comment: try `~/.config/composer/auth.json`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Composer global files can usually be found at your home directory:

In a *nix system that is:

```bash
~/.composer # early composer 0/1 and 2 upgraded from it
~/.config/composer # composer 1/2+
```

`auth.json` is in there as well (if there is a global one).

In a more general sense, on any system, you should be able to find this by executing:

```sh
composer config --list --global
```

or

```sh
composer global config --list
```

Look for the `home` key.

On my system, doing.

```sh
composer config --list --global | grep home
```

results in:

```
[home] /Users/yivi/.composer
```

Comment: In my case it was located at ~/.config/composer
Dont know who and how do it, but maybe it also possible for others.
Found this file with command find ~/ -name "auth.json"