# Cannot install "global" composer requirements because "composer.json is not writeable"

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to install Laravel but again and again I got the below error,

> rukon@rukon-HP-Notebook:~$ composer global require laravel/installer
> Changed current directory to /home/rukon/.config/composer
> ./composer.json is not writable. rukon@rukon-HP-Notebook:~$

I tried to make writable composer.json by

```
$chmod 777 ./composer.json
```

but it's not working. my file owner is not root

Comment: to clarify, `./composer.json` refers to `/home/rukon/.config/composer/composer.json` right?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Can you share the current permissions of that file?

Answer (score 1):

When you run any `composer global` command, the `composer.json` used is the one at your HOME directory, not at your projects directory. E.g. at `~/.composer/composer.json`.

Looks like your **home** directory composer is owned by root.

At some point you've executed `composer` with root and messed up your installation.

To find out where your composer's home directory is at, you should run this (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66356332/1426539)):

```
composer config --list --global | grep home
```

E.g. given your output, it seems your home directory sits at "/home/rukon/.config/composer":

So you'd need to run:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.config/composer
```

To fix your "global" composer configuration directory.

You should be able to run `composer global` commands after that.

If you have more permissions problems, you'd better fix your home directory so everything in there is owned by your user, and nothing by root as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/829539/481096):

```
sudo find ~ -type d -user root -exec sudo chown -R $USER: {} +
```

For a regular installation the above should be safe (all the files in your home directory belong to to your own user), but if you have anything special in there you should probably be aware and take a more surgical approach (checking each directory).

Comment: rukon@rukon-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.composer
[sudo] password for rukon: 
chown: cannot access '/home/rukon/.composer': No such file or directory
rukon@rukon-HP-Notebook:~$                                                                                                            it's showing this.

Comment: rukon@rukon-HP-Notebook:~$ composer config --list --global | grep home
[vendor-dir] vendor (/home/rukon/vendor)
[bin-dir] {$vendor-dir}/bin (/home/rukon/vendor/bin)
[cache-dir] /home/rukon/.cache/composer
[data-dir] /home/rukon/.local/share/composer
[cache-files-dir] {$cache-dir}/files (/home/rukon/.cache/composer/files)
[cache-repo-dir] {$cache-dir}/repo (/home/rukon/.cache/composer/repo)
[cache-vcs-dir] {$cache-dir}/vcs (/home/rukon/.cache/composer/vcs)
[home] /home/rukon/.config/composer
it's showig this

Comment: rukon@rukon-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo chown -R $user ~/
[sudo] password for rukon: 
chown: missing operand after ‘/home/rukon/’
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
rukon@rukon-HP-Notebook:~$                        after giving this command i tried also for laravel installation but there have problem on cache folder

Comment: Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

                                                                               
  [ErrorException]                                                             
  copy(/home/rukon/.cache/composer/files/laravel/installer/62491603ec89eb9d8c  
  fec6fdc1ee7d3ae2ffce42.zip): Failed to open stream: Permission denied                Showing now this error when give the command $composer global require laravel/installer

Comment: Your home directory permissions are broken. Try to use the solution above and the linked answer to fix your home directory permissions. And try not to run composer as root in the future.