# Could not fetch [repository], please review your configured GitHub OAuth token when running "composer update"

Tags: php, composer-php, github-api

When I run `composer update`, I get the following error:

> Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator/zipball/cf1c2e7c203ac650e352f4cc675a7021e7d1b3cf, please review your configured GitHub OAuth token or enter a new one to access private repos. When working with public GitHub repositories only, head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=&description=Composer to retrieve a token.

Then I go to "https://github.com/settings/tokens/new", generate a new token and set it using the following command:

```sh
composer config --global github-oauth.github.com [token]
```

even after that, when I run `composer update` I get the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a temporary issue, maybe? The repo in question is not a private repository.

Answer (score 15):

You are missing `--auth` in the command.
The command should be:

```
composer config --global --auth github-oauth.github.com [token]
```

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem and it was due to incorrect credentials in my `auth.json` file. Two suggestions:

- Either define the correct credentials in the [`auth.json`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/authentication-for-private-packages.md) file as described in the docs:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "example.org": {
            "username": "username",
            "password": "password"
        }
    },
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "ghp_your_token_here"
    }
}
```

- Or if you don't need this, just delete the `auth.json` file.

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Where to find the auth.json?

Comment: run this command it will let you know where your file is. composer config --list --global | grep home

Comment: I was using publicly accessible repositories, and the auth.json credentials were getting in the way. I temporarily deleted the files. Or you can add proper credentials there. These instructions might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66355868/where-is-composers-global-auth-json-located

Comment: After deleting json file it works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the `composer.lock` file and running the `composer update` command again.